# El Capitan graphics don't wake from sleep / WindowServer process at 100%

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

Running 10.11.4 on a MacBook Pro Retina 15-inch Late 2013.

Device is generally connected to an external display. When slept for a "long" period of time (more than an hour?) the graphics often don't "wake up". When I ssh into the box I see CPU for the WindowServer process at 100%. I have tried closing every running application (in /Applications) while the computer is in this state without resolving the issue. I have to restart the machine.

I have tried resetting the SMC and have disabled Automatic graphics switching. This problem began only within the past couple of weeks, but I can't trace to the installation of any given piece of software.

Thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I've got the same issue. Only started happening in the past month or so (maybe with 10.11.4?). Sleep for a short time is fine (~1hr), but whenever I get into work (sleep for ~10hours), i wake up to a painfully slow machine until I do a reset. I tried closing all applications before sleep, but to no avail. WindowServer also as unreasonably high CPU. Mid 2015 15-inch Retina, 16GB RAM. 2GB Graphics. 2.5ghz i7. Thunderbolt Display always connected.

Comment: My Thunderbolt Display's logic board was replaced last week. The ethernet port was dead. The problem seems to be fixed for me. @Ben, are you also using an Apple display?